# How to get all the records of specific type?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am a new user of LINQ and I am trying to develop a simple method that will retrieve all the records for each specific type.

Here's is my database schema:

```
Items Table: ID, Code, ItemTypeID, Name, StatusID
ItemType Table: ID, Name
Status Table: ID, Status
```

As you see, there is a relationship between Items and ItemType tables, and there is another one between Items and Status tables.

What I want is to create a method that will retrieve all items under each status. For example, I have 3 statuses; Active, Inactive, Pending. **So how can I retrieve all the items under each status?** Should I develop one method for each status? Should I use Enum?

So far, I came up with the general GetDate() method for Items Table:

```
// Properties
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Code { get; set; }
public int ItemTypeID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public int StatusID { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<Items> getDate()
{
    List<Items> itemsList = new List<Items>();
    using (ItemsDBEntities context = new ItemsDBEntities())
    {
        itemsList =
            (from item in context.Items
            select new Items()
            {
                Code = item.Code,
                Name = item.Name
            }).ToList();
    }
    return itemsList;
}
```

Comment: possibly you need [group clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb384063.aspx), or [join..into clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb311040.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum ItemStatus   //in accordance with the Status Table
 {
   Active = 1,
   Inactive = 2,
   Pending = 3
 }

  public IEnumerable<Items> getDate(params ItemStatus[] selectStatus)
    {       
      using (var context = new ItemsDBEntities())
      {
         return context.Items
               .where(item=> selectStatus.Contains((ItemStatus)item.StatusID))
               .select new Items()
                {
                 Code = item.Code,
                 Name = item.Name,
                 StatusID = item.StatusID 
                }).ToList();
        }         
    }
```

And using:

```
var listItems = getDate(ItemStatys.Active, ItemStatys.Inactive); //needed category
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. Is there anyway of making it generic instead of hardcoded the Status? Which one is better?

Comment: you can use t4 template for status enum

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you need use [join..into clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb311040.aspx) like this

```
public Dictionary<string,IEnumerable<Items>> getData()
{

    using (ItemsDBEntities context = new ItemsDBEntities())
    {
        return (from status in context.Status
                join item in context.Items on status.ID equals item.StatusID into itemsByStatus
                select new 
                {
                    StatusName = status.Status,
                    items = itemsByStatus.Select(i=>
                        new Items()
                        {
                            Code = i.Code,
                            Name = i.Name,
                            StatusID = i.StatusID 
                        })
                }).ToDictionary(e=>e.StatusName, e=>e.items);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
for your scenario from comment

`getData` return dictionary where `Keys` is all statuses names, when you select status in dropdown list you must bind gridview to value from dictionary like this

```
var selectedStatus = dropdownlist.SelectedValue;
var data = getData();

gridView.DataSource = data[selectedStatus];
gridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. However, I am trying to use your method with a DropDownList Control that will list all statuses and based on the selected value, a GridView will be displayed with showing the items with that selected status. Could you please tell me how to use your method with this scenario?